# how to implement error logger file in php

Tags: php, error-handling

I have created one error logger file in PHP and called it from mail index.php file when I tried to log error occurs during calling web API,the error logger file is not created and also not able to error into logger file can anyone help me in this??

looger.php

```
<?php
    class Logger {
        static $directoryName = 'log/';
        static $fileName = 'error.json';

        public static function init() {
            function handleError($code, $description, $file = null, $line = null, $context = null) {
                list($error, $log) = mapErrorCode($code);
                throw new LoggerException($description, $code, $file, $line, $context, $log, $error);
            }
            function handleException($ex) {
                throw new LoggerException($ex->getMessage(), $ex->getCode(), $ex->getFile(), $ex->getLine());
            }

            function mapErrorCode($code) {
                $error = $log = null;
                switch ($code) {
                    case E_PARSE:
                    case E_ERROR:
                    case E_CORE_ERROR:
                    case E_COMPILE_ERROR:
                    case E_USER_ERROR:
                        $error = 'Fatal Error';
                        $log = LOG_ERR;
                        break;
                    case E_WARNING:
                    case E_USER_WARNING:
                    case E_COMPILE_WARNING:
                    case E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR:
                        $error = 'Warning';
                        $log = LOG_WARNING;
                        break;
                    case E_NOTICE:
                    case E_USER_NOTICE:
                        $error = 'Notice';
                        $log = LOG_NOTICE;
                        break;
                    case E_STRICT:
                        $error = 'Strict';
                        $log = LOG_NOTICE;
                        break;
                    case E_DEPRECATED:
                    case E_USER_DEPRECATED:
                        $error = 'Deprecated';
                        $log = LOG_NOTICE;
                        break;
                    default :
                        break;
                }
                return array($error, $log);
            }
            error_reporting(E_ALL);
            ini_set("display_errors", "off");            
            set_error_handler("handleError");
            set_exception_handler("handleException");
        }
        public static function save($e, $customMessage = '', $customData = []) {

            if (!isset($e)) {
                $bt = debug_backtrace();
                $caller = array_shift($bt);
                if (isset($caller)) {
                    $e = new LoggerException($customMessage, 0, $caller['file'], $caller['line'], null, null, 'NoException');
                } else {
                    $e = new LoggerException($customMessage, 0, null, null, null, null, 'NoException');
                }
            }
            date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
            $logData = Logger::get($e, $customMessage, $customData);            
            $now = date('d_m_Y');

            $directoryName = Logger::$directoryName;
            $fileName = Logger::$fileName;
            if (!file_exists($directoryName)) {
                mkdir($directoryName);
            }
            $fileName = $directoryName . $now . '_' . $fileName;  
            if (!file_exists($fileName)) {
                $file = fopen($fileName, "w");
                fclose($file);
            }

            $jsonData = file_get_contents($fileName);
            $arrayData = json_decode($jsonData, true);
            if (!isset($arrayData)) {
                $arrayData = [];                
            }
            array_push($arrayData, $logData);
            $jsonData = json_encode($arrayData, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
            return file_put_contents($fileName, $jsonData);
        }
        public static function get($e, $customMessage = '', $customData = []) {
            $error = get_class($e) == 'LoggerException' ? $e->getError() : get_class($e);
            $context = [
                'HTTP_HOST'          => $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'],
                'HTTP_CONNECTION'    => $_SERVER['HTTP_CONNECTION'],
                'HTTP_USER_AGENT'    => $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],                
                'REMOTE_ADDR'        => $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'],                
                'REMOTE_PORT'        => $_SERVER['REMOTE_PORT'],
                'REQUEST_SCHEME'     => $_SERVER['REQUEST_SCHEME'],
                'REQUEST_METHOD'     => $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'],
                'REQUEST_URI'        => $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],
                'QUERY_STRING'       => $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],
                'PHP_SELF'           => $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'],
                'REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT' => $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT'],
                'REQUEST_TIME'       => $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME'],
                'GET'                => $_GET,
                'POST'               => $_POST,
                'POST_BODY'          => file_get_contents('php://input'),
                'FILES'              => $_FILES,
                'COOKIE'             => $_COOKIE,                
            ];
            return array(
                'level' => $error,
                'code' => $e->getCode(),
                'error' => $error,
                'description' => $e->getMessage(),
                'file' => $e->getFile(),
                'line' => $e->getLine(),        
                'date' => date('d-m-Y h:i:s a'),        
                'message' => $error . ' (' . $e->getCode() . '): ' . $e->getMessage() . ' in [' . $e->getFile() . ', line ' . $e->getLine() . ']',
                'customMessage' => $customMessage,
                'customData' => $customData,
                'context' => $context
            );
        }
    }

    class LoggerException extends ErrorException {

        private $context = null;
        private $log = null;
        private $error = null;
        function __construct($description, $code, $file = null, $line = null, $context = null, $log = null, $error = null) {
            parent::__construct($description, 0, $code, $file, $line);
            $this->context = $context;
            $this->log = $log;
            $this->error = $error;
        }
        public function getContext() {
            return $this->context;
        }
        public function getLog() {
            return $this->log;
        }
        public function getError() {
            return $this->error;
        }
    }

    Logger::init();
?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
include_once './api/logger.php';


 $url = 'http://localhost/jwt_api/api/login1.php';

        //open connection
        $postdata = json_encode($data);
        //print_r($postdata);
        $ch = curl_init($url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *', 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST', 'Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        $result = json_decode($output);
        if ($result->message == 'Successful login') {
            $jwtname = "Access";
            $jwt = $result->jwt;
            setcookie($jwtname, $jwt, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
            header("location:create.php");
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $http_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        //echo $http_code;
        //trigger_error("Number cannot be less than 10");
        //Logger::save($e);
        curl_close($ch);
```

As shown above, $http_code return me error response code, now I want to log that error in my logger.php file, I try both trigger_error and also Logger:: save() method but not able to log my custom error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever we define the file path directly like in your case 'error.json' we assumed it must be created in the current directory if we specify no other directory location but normally it doesn't happen.

I have also faced it a lot of time because it always creates the file in some other location. That is why **DIR** is introduced in PHP.

By using **DIR** you can get the location of the current directory and then create the file, like:

```
$file = __DIR__.'/error.json';
```

This will create error.json in the current directory with a guarantee. However, if you want to create it in the log directory then firstly specify the location of log directory by defining a global variable in the config file of your project like this:

```
define("LOG", (dirname(dirname(__DIR__)));
```

Use dirname as much time according to your need. Like if there is the hierarchy var->log and var->log->html->your project->config.php then you will use dirname 2 times like above because there are 2 directories gap between log and config file directory.

After making LOG global variable you can use it in any file of your project and always get the correct path regardless of file location by using:

```
$file = LOG.'/error.json';
```

Comment: how to called and tracked my errors  from my index.php file

Comment: You are writing errors in save method of Logger class but where you are calling save method in init function? It seems that save method is define but not calling that is why no errors will track.

Comment: Maryam Aslam, can you show me how to called init method in index.php?? so i dnt need to used set_error_handler method in index.php??

Comment: There is no need to call init method in index.php. Logger class file path already included in your index.php and init is also already called in Logger. Your init function is working but your error.json will be empty because you are not calling save method.

Comment: yes,how to called save method in index.php and can i used set_error_handler function for using it??

Comment: Maryam Aslam how to called save method from index.php

Comment: 1) Firstly it is not a good practice to write nested functions, Your write 3 functions in init function, remove this and write them individual.

2) You are setting your on error handler but didn't trigger it. In index.php when when response is returned , use if else condition here, if result not found then use trigger_error() , it will trigger your custom handler.

3) Make $error, $code and other variables static and declare outside the function.

4) Set these static variables in mapErrorCode.

5) Get these variables in save method and them write in a file.

Comment: 6) In init function firstly call handlerError function then handleException and then save function.

Hopefully I explained you all the modification in detail.